# Kotlin handle indexOutOfBounds for nested list objects

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I have an nested list objects. like the one below. How do I avoid indexOutOfBounds exception? Is there a idiomatic way to do it?

```
listA[0].listB[0].listC[0].department
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getOrNull` (or `elementAtOrNull`, same thing) and chain the calls with null-checking:

```
listA.getOrNull(0)?.listB?.getOrNull(0)?.listC?.getOrNull(0)?.department
```

[There are a few alternatives](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/#kotlin.collections.List) (e.g. `getOrElse`) which let you handle the fallback value in different ways, but using nullable calls chained like this is the typical way to safely access nested properties/items where something in the chain may be null.

Don't forget you can also add the `?:` elvis operator after the call to return a different value if something in the chain produced null.